# put example code in documentation by using sandcastle

Tags: c#, documentation, sandcastle

i'm generating documentation files from the xml comments of my c# code, by using sandcastle help file builder. do you know how to include code examples into the help file, like msdn style?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try the `<example>` and `<code>` tags? It should do what you want.

```
<summary> ... </summary>
<example>This is a code example:
  <code> ... </code>
</example>
```

Comment: And if you're using SHFB ( http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB ) you can add the language of the code too, that way you'll also get code colorization.